# Are there nonconstant smooth families of hypersurfaces over the affine line?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Fix $d\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $S=\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ be the affine line over the complex numbers and let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n_S$ a family of smooth hypersurfaces of degree $d$ over $S$. By this I mean that $X$ is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n_S$ such that the fiber $X_s$ of $X\to S$ over any closed point $s$ of $S$ is a smooth hypersurface of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$.

I say that the family $X$ is *essentially constant* if for any two  closed points $s,s'$ of $S$ there is a linear change of coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ that sends $X_s$ to $X_{s'}$.

My question is: Is there a family of smooth hypersurfaces of degree $d$ over $S$ which is not essentially constant?

If such a family would exist, then there would be a non-constant polynomial map $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}[x_0,\ldots,x_n]_d$ whose image does not intersect the discriminant which is not just given by applying an element of $\textrm{GL}_{n+1}(\mathbb{C}[t])$ to a certain polynomial. I was not able to construct such a map even for $n=1$ and $d=4$ which is probably the first non-trivial case.

Comment: I believe such a family cannot extend to $\mathbb{P}^1$ since the discriminant is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P} \operatorname{Sym}^d(\mathbb{C}^n)$, so intersects any projective curve $C = f(\mathbb{P}^1)$. Even allowing the hypersurface over $\infty$ to be singular, the discriminant locus has to intersect $C$ at a single point, and this point has to be maximally ramified for $f$.